# Ballerina For Loop

Tags: wso2, ballerina

Is there a for loop in ballerina like the for loop in java. I could only find foreach and while loop in the [Ballerina Documentation](http://ballerina.io).

```
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){ 
        //some logic
    }
```

Comment: I dont know ballerina.. but I've just googled for "ballerina for loop statement" and got the answer.. did you do the same? Don't think so

Answer (score 6):

Ballerina language has two looping constructs: `while` and `foreach`.

The `while` statement executes the while-block until the boolean expression evaluates to `false`.

The `foreach` statement iterates over a sequence of items. Executes the foreach-block for each and every item in the sequence.

Your requirement is to iterate over an ordered sequence of numbers. Ballerina support integer range expressions which create arrays of integers. e.g. 0...9 produces the range 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. You can find more on integer ranges [here](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/integer-ranges.html)

Here is the `foreach` with integer ranges.

```
import ballerina/io;

function main (string... args) {
    foreach var i in 0...9 {
        io:println(i);    
    }   
}
```

Comment: In Ballerina 1.0.5 this has the non-obvious limitation that the integer range expressions only increment. I.e. `foreach var i in 9...0 { io:println(i); } compiles but prints nothing.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't have a for loop. Unlike in Java same could be achieved with ballerina foreach easily with closed integer ranges as below.

```
foreach i in 0 ... 9 {
        //some logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Ballerina 0.990.2, variable type should be declared.

```
    foreach int i in 0 ... 9 {
        //some logic
}
```

Comment: This does not add anything that wasn't already in the answer by Tharik Kanaka from 2018-07-05.

Comment: Actually it does, the type of the 'i' is new syntax in 0.990.x

Answer (score 1):

Ballerina 2201.5.0 onward, you can also use the [`int:range` langlib function](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.int/latest#range) in a `foreach` statement.

```
foreach int i in int:range(0, 10, 1) {
    io:print(i, " "); // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
}
```

Unlike with the range expression (e.g., `0 ... 9`), the range function allows specifying an arbitrary integer as the difference between successive integers (both increment and decrement).

```
foreach int i in int:range(0, 10, 2) {
    io:print(i, " "); // 0 2 4 6 8 
}
```

The [release note](https://ballerina.io/downloads/swan-lake-release-notes/swan-lake-2201.5.0#introduction-of-the-intrange-lang-library-function) also includes more details.